# Deduction Theorem and Closed Formulas

Tags: logic

Why in the Deduction Theorem do we require a *closed* formula?

**Deduction Theorem.**  Let $A$ be a closed formula in $T$.  For every formula $B$ of $T$, $\vdash_T A \implies B$ iff $B$ is a theorem of $T[A]$.

I could not find any counterexample.

Can you explain me where is the problem?

**Edit:**

I found a counterexample.

> if $A=C$ and $B=\forall(x)C$

when A is not a closed formula.

Comment: There are many (essentially equivalent)ways to define a deduction in first-order logic. Some ways use only  "closed" formulas (sentences). Some ways allow open formulas (formulas with free occurrences of variables.

Comment: this is my http://i.imgur.com/k1UHDdv.png define

Comment: I have seen versions of the Deduction Theorem in which "$A$" need not be closed. They are a little more complicated.

Comment: What book/source is this from?

Comment: Shoenfield - Mathematical Logic

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you edit it to make it clear just what you are asking?

Comment: $ A=C$ is not a formula (in the logical sence)

Comment: It is right, for $C$ with $x$ free. Consider $C(x) := (x=0)$; from it, by *generalization* we can derive $\forall x (x=0)$. But we cannot conclude with : $(x=0) \rightarrow \forall x (x=0)$ because it is not *true* [For $0$ as value for $x$ the antecedent is *true*, while the consequent is clearly *false*; thus the conditional is false].

Comment: You can find in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923276/what-is-the-justsification-for-this-restriction-on-ug) more details.

Comment: Also see this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/580692/630

Answer (score 3):

In the system of Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811357) (1967) the restriction on $A$ being *closed* is needed in the proof of the **Deduction Theorem** [see page 33] in order to apply the $\exists$-introduction rule [se page 21] :

> if $x$ is not free in $B$, infer $\exists x A \rightarrow B$ from $A \rightarrow B$.

Without the proviso on $B$ in the rule, we can derive the invalid $\exists x (x=0) \rightarrow (x=0)$ from the tautology : $(x=0) \rightarrow (x=0)$.